# How to interpret posterior probability of an regression variable?

Tags: regression, bayesian, mcmc, winbugs, r2winbugs

I am using the following model in WINBUGS to run a hierarchical Bayesian regression where the `beta` are my covariates:

[image]

If I modify this model by adding the following code:

```
# posterior probabilities of Positive beta's
p.beta0 <- step( beta0 )
p.beta1 <- step( beta1 )
```

Then I can assess the posterior probability (`PP`) of the (positive or negative) association of the beta covariates.

My beta values are:

```
beta0 = 0.23434
beta1 = -0.4582
```

With this code, the `PP` of `beta0` is `0.959033`, while the `PP` of `beta1` is `0.015043`. My interpretation for `beta0` is that there is a 95.9033% positive association for this covaraite. However, I am not sure how to interpret for `beta1` since this has a negative association and a low posterior probability. I am not sure if it is an issue with my code for computing the Posterior Probabilities.

Any insight is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`beta` are your regression coefficients, not the covariates. To understand `beta0` and `beta1` you have to look at the model. Part of it says that `log(mu[i]) = beta0 + beta1*aff[i]/10`, where `mu[i]` is the cancer rate of area `i`. `exp(beta0)` shows you the average cancer rate over all areas with aff = 0. Because `beta1 = -0.4582` is negative, cancer rate reduces when aff increases: every time you increase aff by 10, the log cancer rate decreases by 0.4582.